# Multicolored outlines (For Blender Render)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, color, freestyle

I want to give to my model a outline with multiple colors.
[image]

As you can see in this image, the outlines are slighty darker than the material they surround. How can I do something like that in Blender (Render mode)?

Using the "Freestyle" outlines I can only get one color outline like this:
[image]

Comment: I think this can only be achieved if each different colored outline belongs to a different object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the Freestyle rendering option enabled, you will find the Freestyle Line panel showing up in the Material properties window.  The color selector in this panel allows you to choose a line color associated to the material.  The line color can then be referenced using the Material color modifier in the Freestyle Line Style panel in the Render Layers properties window.

[image]

At material boundaries, you might want to use the Priority parameter in the Freestyle Line panel to give a precedence to one of two competing line colors at material boundaries.  [A post in the Freestyle development blog](https://freestyleintegration.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/line-color-priority/) details this feature if you're interested.

Comment: What about Cycles material?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pretty easy setup to play with.

1. Change your material to have a custom color on the edge of the fresnel fall-off. I did this with two diffuse nodes, one grey for the main portion of my objects, and one a green color, and then used a mix node with the factor being my fresnel output.
2. Play with the Fresnel value to your liking.
3. "Green-Screen" out your green in the compositor with chroma key.
4. "Alpha Over" this chroma keyed image under a multi colored image (could also be an image strip for some pretty cool effects), by a factor being driven by the Matte output of the Chroma Key.

[image: Node Setup for cycles material & compositor]

If you want to fine tune this, then start playing with the Cutoff value in the Chroma Key Node.

**Note** that I dropped this from 10° to 0.71° and got this result. Ignore the brightness, I just upped my ambient occlusion all the way up.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the freestyle lines in a color that will change according to what is underneath when using 'Multiply' as a color mix mode in the compositor is a possibility. You could use a gray value that will be a darker value of each color, though you won't arrive at a black outline this way in your final composite.[image: overlay of freestyle from scene.001 onto scene] and the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AVIjamRlEXeWQxbXVZdklWYWc/view?usp=sharing)